# Refactor of JS redux code does not run

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, es6-promise

I am trying to do a simple refactor, but can't get it to work - please help.

Simply put...This works:

```
export function fetchPhotos(payload) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(requestPhotos());

    const request = getRequest(payload, dispatch);
    fetch(request)
    .then(response => {
      if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
        dispatch(setHeader(response.headers));
        return response.json();
      } else if (response.status == 401) {
        const error = new Error(response.statusText);
        error.response = response;
        dispatch(notAuthorized());
        throw error;
      }
    })
    .then(data => {
      dispatch(fetchPhotosSuccess(data));
    })
    .catch(err => err);
  };
}
```

But when I refactor like this:

```
export function fetchPhotos(payload) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(requestPhotos());

    const request = getRequest(payload, dispatch);
    fetch(request)
    .then(response => {
      responseHandler(response, dispatch);
    })
    .then(data => {
      dispatch(fetchPhotosSuccess(data));
    })
    .catch(err => err);
  };
}
```

By handling the response in a separate function:

```
function responseHandler(response, dispatch) {
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    dispatch(setHeader(response.headers));
    return response.json();
  } else if (response.status == 401) {
    const error = new Error(response.statusText);
    error.response = response;
    dispatch(notAuthorized());
    throw error;
  }
}
```

it does not work. It seems like `return response.json();` does not return any data...

Comment: You forgot to return - `return  responseHandler(response, dispatch);` or just `=>  responseHandler(response, dispatch)`.

Comment: ohh yeah,  wow wops. Thanks